# parseFloat returns NaN in componentDidMount function attached to ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to manipulate the value of an HTML5 number input's value to equal `min` if a user keys in a value less than `min`.  However, the function fails because my two parseFloats return NaN (and they definitely shouldn't be--I can access both arguments in the console when I use a `debugger`).

```
componentDidMount() {
  const autocorrect = this.props.autoCorrect; // true
  this.inputNode.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
    const value = parseFloat(this.value); // NaN ?
    const minimum = parseFloat(this.min); // NaN ?
    if (this.props.autoCorrect && (value < minimum)) {
      this.value = minimum;
    }
  });
}


render() {
  return (
    <input
      ref={(input) => {
        this.inputNode = input;
      }}
      type='number'
      min={this.props.min}
      value={this.props.value}
    />
  );
}
```

In fact, if I stop the function with a `debugger`, I can force the input's value to change using `this.value = 23`, for example. So what am I overlooking here in my function?

Comment: Could your input value be blank?

Comment: Binding the event to blur could cause a problem with some browsers, try adding a logging statement in your blur listener to print the value to the console. It might reveal something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions do not define their own context - `this` in your `(e) => {...}` is the same as the conext in which `componentDidMount` was called.

Comment: You're right. That does seem to be connected to the problem.  But then how can I access the DOM attributes of `this.inputNode` from within the function, besides declaring it as a `const` before hand?

Comment: @brogrammer - will `const value = parseFloat(this.inputNode.value);` inside the event handler work?